# Admin > Customers > All Customers > Edit Customer: > left hand tab "Account Information"

Tags: magento2, customer, adminhtml, magento2.3.3

[image]

**How can I populate this field so it's filled in when a customer creates an account?** The value of the field just needs to match what `customer[parent_customer_id]` has. It doesn't necessarily have to happen on account creation.

[image]

The name of the field is `customer[account_number]`

This field is a duplicate but we call it something different and it populates correctly.

The name of that input is `name="customer[parent_customer_id]"`

Even though it's redundant I want both fields to populate. What file and where should I be editing to populate customer[account_number] in its respective field?

**I just need the same default Attribute data that populates `customer[parent_customer_id]` to populate `customer[account_number]`**

Comment: Not a hundred percent sure but I believe this is a DB value so it needs to be through UpgradeData

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail so that i can help you out

Comment: customer[account_number] needs to populate two fields. @HarshJayswal

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you just want to have another field (`account_number`) to populate the same value of customer attribute `parent_customer_id`.

For this you will need to create a `NameSpace/YourModule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_form.xml` and have this content:

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="customer">
        <field name="account_number" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <label translate="true">Account Number</label>
                <dataScope>firstname</dataScope><!--change this "firstname" to "parent_customer_id". My understanding is parent_customer_id is a customer attribute.-->
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you look at my inspect element picture above I already have the field customer[account_number] but just wish to populate it with parent_customer_id @Adarsh Khatri

Comment: Yes, I had seen your image. You will need to add this in your `ui_component` XML file: `<dataScope>parent_customer_id</dataScope>` like I have got it in the answer.